# automatically open a gmail account from a link that will get user and pass from the database

Tags: php, curl, gmail

**is it possible to open gmail directly from my website using php?**

*let say my username and password for my gmail is on my sql database *

then it will auto send the info to gmail when i run the php page, it will get the username and password from the database and open my gmail automatically,, will that be possible or is there any code for this already?

the reason why i want this is that i would want my users to be able to open their gmails without them knowing the password, they would have to go to a link that i provided to be able to open the gmails assigned to them.

i am not aiming to retrieve emails or contacts, what i am trying to achieve is to open gmail from directly from my site or using a link without the need for the user to know the username and password.

Comment: have a look at `imap` and `pop`

Comment: as richie said have a look at imap and pop or use curl

Comment: any sample links would be helpful.

Comment: [Example](http://davidwalsh.name/gmail-php-imap)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible , you can achieve  this by curl ...

use  curl to submit the form login the user in his account and store the cookies for future use , there's a function in  curl to  store cookies and sessions ..

Some useful links

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.curl.php`

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-init.php`

`http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php`

`http://coderscult.com/php-curl-cookies-example/`

Comment: tried that but it doesn't allow me to lof in to gmail, it just displays the google login screen.

Comment: you have to use this url to   submit the form { https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLoginAuth } .. there are many hidden fields too make sure you inspect the form care fully and submit every important field

Comment: yes i am using that, the problem is when i click the submit button it just redirects me to that page.

Answer (score 0):

The cookie example is no longer online.

```
<?php

/* STEP 1. let’s create a cookie file */

$ckfile = tempnam ("/tmp", "CURLCOOKIE");

/* STEP 2. visit the homepage to set the cookie properly */

$ch = curl_init ("http://somedomain.com/");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* STEP 3. visit cookiepage.php */

$ch = curl_init ("http://somedomain.com/cookiepage.php");
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $ckfile);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec ($ch);

/* here you can do whatever you want with $output */

?>
```

Thanks to Mike (The Cult Master)